# Music theory - minim over beats 2 and 3 in 4/4

Tags: theory, notation, rhythm

When writing the rhythm crotchet - minim - crotchet in 4/4, is this ok or should it be 4 crotchets with the 2nd and 3rd tied together? I know that you can't write a minim rest over beats 2 and 3 in 4/4 so is it the same when writing notes?

Comment: You should always avoid ties where possible. So I read.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Notating half notes across beat 3 in 4/4](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/48544/notating-half-notes-across-beat-3-in-4-4)

Answer (score 3):

The basic 'rule' - 4/4 bars should be split into two equal halves. That way they're easier to read. But if there's only a minim breaking that 'rule', it's not difficult to read anyway. And more and more, written music seems to be ignoring that, which makes some not so easy to read. The whole purpose of writing dots on paper is so that they can be read as easily as possible. That just needs to be considered first and foremost.